# Log out from admin as non-admin

Tags: windows, windows-10

I logged into a PC as Admin to take out some user's local admin privileges, and that was that.

Only...I forgot to log out as Admin. Now the user's about 1000 miles away and can't do anything. Can't use "other account" because he's not in our domain, can't get into our domain, because he needs a VPN for that. Can't start a VPN because it's behind the login page.

Now what? How can the user force change account to his own account?

Comment: Can he reboot ?

Comment: Yes, the user can!

Comment: So why doesn't he reboot?